# Server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am stuck because I cannot do a simple redirect using JSF. My redirect code is:

```
if (!ischangelicense && source == 1) {
            System.out.println("Here*****: Should redirect here");
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ConfigurableNavigationHandler nav = (ConfigurableNavigationHandler) fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            nav.performNavigation("login?faces-redirect=true");
        }
```

At browser I get `server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete` with a suggestion to enable cookies. The cookies are enabled and am not sure what else to check. The line `Here*****: Should redirect here` prints multiple times and am not sure why either. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you redirecting this way? [mcve] please...

Comment: This basically means that the page behind `"login?faces-redirect=true"` is re-executing this piece of code again, which will navigate to `"login?faces-redirect=true"` again. In other words: it's a simple infinite loop. Probably you shouldn't re-execute that piece of code when the page behind `"login?faces-redirect=true"` is opened? That would be a logical solution.